# Script google sheet que muestre valor o dato de una celda

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Requiero realizar un script que pueda abrir en un cuadro de diálogo el valor o dato en una celda.

Por ejemplo si en A1 esta "Hola" asignar el script a un botón que al tocarlo el cuadro dialogo diga "Hola" y que al cambiar el dato en A1 el cuadro de dialogo cambie??? encontré este código pero es para excel y no funciona en google sheet, lo dejo como ejemplo.

```
Sub valueDemo ()
MsgBox Worksheets ( "Sheet1" ) .range ( "A1" ) .value
End Sub
```

Comment: Cambié un poco la redacción del primer enunciado para adecuarlo al tipo de preguntas que se pueden hacer en este sitio. En relación al código parece que has tomado código de VBA para Excel en lugar de Google Apps Script. Revisa las preguntas de [tag:google-apps-script] seguramente encontrarás ejemplos que si funcionen.

Comment: Si como yo mismo indique en él post inicial él código VBA es de Excel y como también indique solo lo puse como ejemplo. Y claro que busque en él foro antes de hacer mi pregunta pero no encontré nada... Gracias por las correcciónes, pero tiene idea del script que busco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Class UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) tiene varios métodos para mostrar diferentes tipos de diálogos. Si sólo se trata de mostrar el valor de una celda usa `alert`. El siguiente ejemplo muestra el valor de la celda A1 de la hoja activa:

```
function mostrarValorA1(){
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue());
}
```

Para agregar un botón, inserta una image, luego haz clic con el botón derecho en ella y selecciona asignar script. Luego escribes el nombre de la función (sin paréntesis). En el caso del ejemplo escribe `mostrarValorA1`.

Comment: Esto podría cambiarse para funcionar en algunas hojas seleccionadas? tengo un libro con los 12 meses, Enero, Febrero, etc pero este tipo de script solo me funciona en la primer hoja.

Comment: @JimmyVA, getActiveSheet() devuelve la hoja actual, hay otros métodos como getSheets(), getSheetByName(), etc. que podrías usar. Creo que tenemos preguntas que usan estos métodos, pero si no encuentras una, publícala tú.